# Publish ASP.Net Core App on local IIS - Content not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

I created a project in Visual Studio Code using following command:

`dotnet new angular --use-local-db`

Thereafter I updated angular from version 8 to 10 and finished the project. I tested using

`dotnet watch run`

All worked fine for me and I tried to publish it on my local IIS. Sadly I will not get it run. I tried different solutions found on several pages ended up using Visual Studio to publish the project on IIS. I used the following instructions, except Code First Migration because the necessary database already exists:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis#create-the-publish-profile

The problem is that if I do so, Visual Studio will create an "application" called, let's say, "myproject". When I then run "Browse..." on it I will get following errors in console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    style. ... .css`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    runtime-es2015. ... .css`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    polyfills-es2015. ... .css`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    main-es2015. ... .css`

The mentioned folders are on the mentioned directory ('ClientApp\dist'). Is there anything I missed to configure or set up?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit after first reply:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    ...
    app.UseRouting();
    ...
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

---

Edit after second reply:

Here a some directories/paths. Hope the needed once are found here.

Project Structur

```
[Root]
    ClientApp
        src
            app
                [Angular Web App related files]
                app.module.ts
                ...
            main.js
            index.html
            styles.css
            polyfills.ts
            ...
        package.json
        angular.json
    [ASP.NET Core Web API Files]
    appsettings.json
    [Project].csproj
    Program.cs
    Startup.cs
```

IIS Files

```
wwwroot
    [Project]
        ClientApp
            dist
                index.html
                main. ... .js
                polyfills. ... .js
                runtime. ... .js
                styles. ... .css
        [ASP.NET Core Web API Files]
```

How I call the project in browser:

```
localhost/[Project]
```

Paths shown when I press ctrl+U and try to access the files:

```
Requested URL: localhost:Port/main. ... .js
Physical Path: ...\wwwroot\main. ... .js
```

---

**New Observation:**

If I modify index.html of the angular client from

```
 <base href="/" />
```

to

```
 <base href="/[projectname]/" />
```

The page is loading in Prod on IIS but it fails in development mode.
Also then in Prod on IIS it uses the url localhost/api/[controller] instead of working url localhost/[projectname]/api/[controller]. Last mentioned url I can access by entering it to the browser and it returns the data.

If I then modifiy the service file for the controller from

```
...
return this.http.get('/api/[controller]')
...
```

to

```
...
return this.http.get('[projectname]/api/[controller]')
...
```

it tries to access path: localhost/[projectname]/[projectname]/api/[controller]

Any Idea what I missconfigured or where I need to change configuration so that the project works in Prod and Dev Mode?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your URLs are alright, press **control + U** and try to click on your CSS files paths, and make sure the path is alright, then look for the MIME types to allow from the IIS manager.

Comment: First, thank you for your feedback and sorry for the delay in response.

I clicked on the path and get "404 - Not Found". So this seems to be the issue.

The physical path shows that it tries to find the files in the wwwroot folder. 

I'm not sure how to fix this. I add the information in my Startup.cs to the main post.

Comment: Did I missconfigured something or is there anything missing?

Comment: Can you show me you file path and Project structure? check your paths, you may need to use a relative path instead of an absolute. Finally, check your IIS settings and make sure you can server Static files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I hope I got the point:

Project structure is more or less the default from `dotnet new angular` so api files and startup.cs, program.cs is on the root. Angular files in ClientApp.

The published code on IIS "Server" is located at the root, so it's `wwwroot\[Project] -> API Files` and for `wwwroot\[Project]\ClientApp\dist -> Angular Web Client Files`.

As I understand it should use physical path `wwwroot\[Project]\ClientApp\dist` but uses `wwwroot\[Project]` to get the necessary files.

Are this the information you need?

Comment: BTW: Static Files as Feature is enabled for IIS. Do you mean this with your last hint?

Comment: There is no problem with your path, you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to get more detailed information

Comment: Thanks for the help again. The log shows that it tries to find the path on the root of wwwroot directory and not at wwwroot\\[Projektname]\ClientApp\dist. I do not understand what I need to configure to direct the request to the desired path. I thought the current settings should do it already.

Comment: Using failed request tracking what kind of information should I watch for? Currently it looks like there are not more information which could be a hint what causing this error.